# Convergence of Gamma Function Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, gamma-function

I was able to show that the integral formula for the gamma function

$$\Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-x}dx$$

is uniformly convergent for $s$ in any closed and bounded interval using the Weierstrass theorem.  Now I would like to show that the convergence is not uniform for all $s > 0$ but am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: It's enough to show that it tends to infinity as s tends to 0. and for this, it's enough to show that $\int_0 ^1 x^{s-1} dx$ tends to infinity as s tends to 0.

Comment: @WoodWorker What do you have tried so far? Please add your efforts, this will help the community to give you a good answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral representation converges for $Re s > 0$.  As an improper integral, convergence is indeed uniform for (real) $s \in [\alpha,\beta]$. However, as you suspect, convergence is not uniform for $s \in (0,\infty)$.  Problems arise due to singular behavior both at $x = 0$ when $s < 1$ and as $x \to \infty$ when $s > 1$.

To show non-uniform convergence consider

$$\Gamma(s) = \Phi(s) + \Psi(s),$$

where

$$\Phi(s) = \int_0^1 x^{s-1} e^{-x} \, dx, \\ \Psi(s) = \int_1^\infty x^{s-1} e^{-x} \, dx.$$

We can show that $\Psi(s)$ fails to converge uniformly for $s \in [\alpha, \infty).$  Note that for any sequence $(s_n)$ such that $s_n \to \infty$ with $s_n > 1 + n/\log n,$  we have

$$\left| \int_n^\infty x^{s_n-1} e^{-x} \, dx\right| > n^{s_n-1}\int_n^\infty e^{-x} \, dx = n^{s_n-1}e^{-n} > 1,$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_n^\infty x^{s_n-1} e^{-x} \, dx \neq 0,$$

and convergence is not uniform.

Similarly, we can show that $\Phi(s)$ fails to converge uniformly for $s \in (0, \beta).$ Note that for $s_n < 1$,

$$\left| \int_{1/2n}^{1/n} x^{s_n-1} e^{-x} \, dx\right| > e^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{s_n-1}\frac{1}{2n} = \frac{1}{2en^{s_n}}.$$

Now take $s_n = 1/n$.  In this case $s_n \to 0$ and $n^{s_n} = n^{1/n} \to 1$.  For all $n$ sufficiently large, we have $n^{1/n} < 2$ and

$$\left| \int_{1/2n}^{1/n} x^{s_n-1} e^{-x} \, dx\right| > \frac{1}{4e}.$$

Comment: (it [converges compactly on $Re(s) > 0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence), this is indeed [a proof that it is analytic there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem))