# How to prove $\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-\alpha x} f(x)dx \rightarrow \int ^{\infty}_{0} f(x) dx$ when $\alpha \rightarrow 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I think I could show that if $$\int ^{\infty}_{0} f(x) dx$$ is convergent, then $$\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-\alpha x} f(x)dx$$ is also convergent for $\alpha>0$. I'm wondering is my proof true?

---

Here's my proof outline:

Because of The Archimedean Property of real numbers:
$$\forall \alpha >0 \; \exists x_{0}\in \mathbb{R} \; (\alpha x>1)$$

We also have:
$$\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-\alpha x} f(x)dx = \int^{x_{0}}_{0} e^{-\alpha x} f(x)dx + \int^{\infty}_{x_{0}} e^{-\alpha x} f(x)dx$$ 
Trivially $\int^{x_{0}}_{0} e^{-\alpha x} f(x)dx$ is finite, and $$\int^{\infty}_{x_{0}} e^{-\alpha x} f(x)dx < \frac{1}{e}\int^{\infty}_{x_{0}} f(x)dx < \infty$$

So $\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-\alpha x} f(x)dx$ converges.

---

And I know it is true to say $$\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-\alpha x} f(x)dx \rightarrow \int ^{\infty}_{0} f(x) dx$$ when $\alpha \rightarrow 0$, but how can I prove it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is $\alpha \ge 0$?

Comment: How do you know that $\int^{\infty}_{x_{0}} e^{-\alpha x} f(x)dx < \frac{1}{e}\int^{\infty}_{x_{0}} f(x)dx$ if $f$ is not nonnegative?

Comment: @VVejalla I fixed it.

Comment: @RRL Does it differ when $f(x)$ is non-negative or not?

Comment: You have $e^{-\alpha x} < e^{-1}$ but how does your inequality follow if $\int_{x_0}^\infty f(x) \, dx < 0$.

Comment: @RRL I don't know. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is absolutely integrable, that is $\int_0^\infty |f(x)| \, dx < \infty$, then the proof is easy.

In this case -- because $|e^{-\alpha x}f(x)| \leqslant |f(x)|$ for all $\alpha \geqslant 0$ -- the improper integral converges uniformly by the Weierstrass M-test.  This implies that $I(\alpha) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x} f(x) \, dx$ is continuous and $\lim_{\alpha\to 0+}I(\alpha) = I(0)$.

More generally -- for example if the improper integral $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx$ is only conditionally convergent --  the result is true as a consequence of Abel's test for the uniform convergence of an improper integral.  Note that  $x \mapsto e^{-\alpha x}$ is monotone with respect to $x \in [0,\infty)$ and is uniformly bounded for all $x \geqslant 0$ and $\alpha \geqslant 0$ since $|e^{-\alpha x}| \leqslant 1$. Additionally, $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx$ is convergent by hypothesis and, therefore, uniformly convergent for $\alpha \geqslant 0$ (trivially since there is no dependence on $\alpha$). Both condition of Abel's test are met and the improper integral is uniformly convergent for $\alpha \geqslant 0$.

To see why $\lim_{\alpha\to 0+}I(\alpha) = I(0)$ is implied by uniform convergence note that for any $ \epsilon > 0$ there exists $C_1>0$ such that for all $c > C_1$ we have (by integrability of $f$)

$$\left|\int_c^\infty f(x) \, dx\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{3},$$

and there exists $C_2>0$ such that for all $c > C_2$ and all $\alpha \geqslant 0$ we have (by uniform convergence of $I(\alpha)$)

$$\left|\int_c^\infty e^{-\alpha x} f(x) \, dx\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$$

Thus, for any $c > \max(C_1,C_2)$ we have

$$\left|\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x} f(x) \, dx - \int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx \right| \\\leqslant \left|\int_0^c e^{-\alpha x} f(x) \, dx - \int_0^c f(x) \, dx \right|+ \left|\int_c^\infty e^{-\alpha x} f(x) \, dx  \right|+ \left|\int_c^\infty f(x) \, dx  \right| \\ \leqslant \int_0^c |e^{-\alpha x} - 1||f(x)| \, dx + \frac{2\epsilon}{3} \\ \leqslant (1- e^{-\alpha c}) \int_0^c |f(x)| \, dx + \frac{2\epsilon}{3}$$

The first term on the RHS can be made smaller than $\epsilon /3$ by choosing $\alpha$ sufficiently close to $0$ and the result $\lim_{\alpha \to 0+} I(\alpha) = I(0)$ follows.

Comment: Could you please help in conditional convergence case?

Comment: How can you explicitly argue that $(1- e^{-\alpha c}) \int_0^c |f(x)| \, dx$ can be made smaller than any $\epsilon >0$?

Comment: @Masoud:  With $c > \max(C_1,C_2)$ held fixed we have $e^{-\alpha c} \to 1$ as $\alpha \to 0+$ and $(1-e^{-\alpha c}) \int_0^c |f(x)| \, dx \to 0$.  The integral over $[0,c]$ is of course finite since under the hypothesis that $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx$ converges, either $f$ is Lebesgue integrable or Riemann integrable on any bounded interval.

Comment: Can Abel's test for uniform convergence also be used for the Mellin transform?  More specifically, if the Mellin transform $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} x^{s}\, \mathrm dx$ converges for $s \in [- \delta, 0]$, $\delta >0$, can Abel's test be used to argue that the convergence is uniform?  The need for $x^{s}$ to be uniformly bounded for all $x \ge 0$ seems to present a problem.

Comment: @RandomVariable:  It would depend on the nature of $f$.  For example if $f(x) = x^\delta e^{-x}$ then the integral reduces to a gamma function $\int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^{\delta + s-1} \, dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^{t-1} \, dx$ where $\delta+s= t \in [0,\delta]$.  As I show [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1986706/148510) this is not uniformly convergent.  It is uniformly convergent for $0 < \alpha \leqslant t \leqslant \delta$.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to post a new question.

Comment: I'm reposting my previous comment because it was worded awkwardly: I was rereading your comment from a couple years ago, and I'm a bit confused why $f(x) = x^{\delta} e^{-x}$ would be a counterexample.  It doesn't satisfy the condition that  $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} x^{s} \, \mathrm dx$ must converge at $s= -\delta$.  I posted a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4235459/16033) a while ago if you wanted to add an answer.

Comment: @RandomVariable: Sorry -- I was unable to respond earlier.  I have to review this.  I have not been very active on this site for the past year.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to pass a limit through an integral; the first is by proving that the limit converges uniformly. The second way is by a significantly more powerful theorem called Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem. Either of these should do the trick -

$$ \lim_{a \to 0} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax}f(x) dx = \int_0^{\infty} \lim_{a \to 0} e^{-ax} f(x) dx = \int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx < + \infty. $$

Can you show that either the convergence is uniform or that the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem applies?

Comment: Also, as VVejalla points out, we need $a \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

We can show that $\int ^{\infty}_{0} e^{-\alpha x}f(x)dx$ is convergent by using [Second Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Second_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals).

---

Here is the outline:

There exists a $c \in (a, b]$ such that:

$$ \int ^{b}_{a}e^{-\alpha x}f(x)dx = (lim _{x \rightarrow a^+} e^{-\alpha x})\int ^c_{a}f(x)dx = e^{-a x}\int ^c_{a}f(x)dx$$
We know that $\mid \int ^c_{a}f(x)dx \mid$ is less than arbitrary $\epsilon >0$ for large enough $a$, so $\mid \int ^{b}_{a}e^{-\alpha x}f(x)dx \mid$ have this property, hence $\int ^{\infty}_{0}e^{-\alpha x}f(x)dx$ is convergent.

---

Now I want to show that $\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-\alpha x} f(x)dx \rightarrow \int ^{\infty}_{0} f(x) dx$ when $\alpha \rightarrow 0$.

We know:
$$\int^{\infty}_{0} f(x)dx - \int ^{\infty}_{0} e^{-\alpha x}f(x) dx = \int ^{A}_{0} (1-e^{-\alpha x})f(x) dx +\int ^{\infty}_{A}f(x) dx -\int ^{\infty}_{A} e^{-\alpha x}f(x) dx$$
Because of convergence the integrals, for large enough $A$ and arbitrary $\epsilon >0$ we have: $$\mid \int ^{\infty}_{A}f(x) dx \mid + \mid \int ^{\infty}_{A} e^{-\alpha x}f(x) dx \mid < \frac{2\epsilon}{3}$$
We can also make $\int ^{A}_{0} (1-e^{-\alpha x})f(x) dx$ smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ by taking $\alpha$ close enough to $0$.
So $\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-\alpha x} f(x)dx \rightarrow \int ^{\infty}_{0} f(x) dx$ when $\alpha \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: You have the correct idea but some details are wrong.  You are not given that $f$ is continuous so your application of the First Mean Value Theorem is not valid.  The first part using the Second Mean Value Theorem is effectively trying to reconstruct a proof of Abel's test for uniform convergence of improper integrals but some steps are wrong -- again because of not being careful about the potential for $f$ to change sign.  Abel's test will in fact work to prove that $\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x} f(x) \, dx$ is uniformly convergent -- as I show in my answer.

Comment: With uniform convergence as I show it follows that $\lim_{\alpha \to 0+} \int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x} f(x) \, dx = \int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx$.

Comment: @RRL I didn't understand what is wrong with usage of Second Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: Use of the Second Mean Value Theorem is fine.  To be perfectly correct you just need to clean up the argument. Just say $\left|\int_a^b e^{-\alpha x} f(x) \, dx  \right| = e^{-\alpha a}\left|\int_a^c f(x) \, dx \right| \leqslant \left|\int_a^c f(x) \, dx \right| $ and the absolute value of the integral on the RHS can be made smaller than any $\epsilon$ by choosing $a$ sufficiently large for any $b > a$.  This proves uniform convergence of the integral.